# Variable returns undefined after assigning value in nightwatch custom command

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

Writing a [custom command](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-custom-commands) for a nightwatch test.

Why cannot I set the value of the `newValidFromText` in the following code snippet?

```
exports.command = function () {

var newValidFromText; //Want to set value to this variable

var browser= this;
browser
    .useCss()
    .perform(function() {

        //Setting the value to the variable 'newValidFromText'
        newValidFromText = "June 1, 2017 "

        //Testing the value set - console prints "June 1, 2017"
        console.log( "newValidFromText now is: "+ newValidFromText );
    })

    .waitForElementVisible('input[id*="SubscriptionStart"]')

    //Test for correct value - getting validFromText = undefined
    .verify.valueContains('input[id*="SubscriptionStart"]', validFromText) 
 return browser.useCss();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in Nightwatch's Documentation pages [Understanding the Command Queue.](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue)

> values captured this way also aren't available until the test is
>   running. In a callback, all code directly in the test case function
>   body has already resolved, and the only place any other code will run
>   is in other callbacks. This is important to keep in mind because it
>   can be easy to think this might work:

```
// incorrect usage of a callback value

var text;
browser
  .getValue('#input', function (result) {
    text = result.value;
  })
  .setValue('#output', text); // WRONG: text is undefined
```

> The problem here is that the setValue() call happens in the main test
>   case function call, before the callback is called when text is still
>   undefined. For setValue() to have the correct value for text, it must
>   be called within, or some time after, the getText() callback:

Answer (score 1):

Because you asked your variable out of visibility zone

```
exports.command = function () {

var newValidFromText; //Want to set value to this variable

var browser= this;
 browser
.useCss()
.perform(function() {

    //Setting the value to the variable 'newValidFromText'
    newValidFromText = "June 1, 2017 "

    //Testing the value set - console prints "June 1, 2017"
    console.log( "newValidFromText now is: "+ newValidFromText );

this.waitForElementVisible('input[id*="SubscriptionStart"]') 

    .verify.valueContains('input[id*="SubscriptionStart"]', validFromText); 

})
```

};

Comment: I agree with this solution. But I would like to know the internals of this.

Comment: While your answer is what I would follow to use the value of the data captured from the callback, i was more interested in why that is the case? To me, [the stuff I found from the documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43786411/2605210) explains the why.

Answer (score 0):

But you can use your custom method for that and it will be like a perfect.

```
customTitle: function () {

var application = this.waitForElementPresent('@selector')
....do something;
return application;
},

you: function() {

 ...code
 .customTitle();
 return you;
 };
```